# Firebase security rules: how to access key of a new map field entry created by a SET operation using merge?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

Let's say I'm issuing an update operation in JavaScript to add an entry to a submap:

```
db.collection('companies').doc(companyId).set({
      employees: {
        [employeeId]: { 
          name: 'Mrs Firebase', 
          id: employeeId
        }
      }
    }, { merge: true })
```

In my security rules, I'd like to get employeeId, the key of the added entry. Is this possible?

I can access a set containing the key, for example:

```
request.resource.data.employees.diff(resource.data.employees).addedKeys()
```

But I see no way of accessing elements of this set.

I'm unsure if there's a way to access elements of this set (e.g. convert the set to a list) or to access the new key some other way.

One reason I want to access the added key is to ensure data integrity, by checking that the key exists elsewhere in the database, for example:

```
exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/employees/$(employeeId))
```

Another reason could be to validate the type or value of the added employeeId.

Comment: Yes, it looks possible.  Please edit the question to explain the specific problem you're running into, along with the code that isn't working the way you expect.  We need a distinct mission statement about what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Thanks. I've done my best to outline the goal. Specific code is difficult, simply because I do not see a way to do this. Using a diff on the sets seemed intuitive, but AFAICT there is no way to access individual elements of a set in the security rules language.

Comment: So you're saying that "employeeId" in the update is not a literal string used as the key to a map, but an actual variable value?

Comment: Ah, yes, sorry, I missed the [ ] around employeeId where I used it in the object, a typo when simplifying the example. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible because there's nothing stopping a client from adding multiple keys at the same time, and there is no iteration in rules to check things in sequence.  It might be better to store this data in a document in a subcollection where the intent is clearly to have one employee stored in a single document identified by that employee's ID.